# SqlCeDataAdapter giving MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, mobile, compact-framework, sql-server-ce

I am running C# console application in window mobile with compact framework. I am try the following code

```
SqlCeDataAdapter dbAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(query, CreateConnection());
dsMobileLog = new DataSet();
dbAdapter.Fill(dsMobileLog);
```

But I found `MissingMethodException` in  `dbAdapter.Fill(dsMobileLog);`

Comment: What using statements do you have included in your code?

Comment: using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data;
using BusinessEntity;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

Comment: You have the System.Data.Common using statement, but is it added to your references? You need to add the reference to the System.Data.Common dll and add the using statement in your code. System.Data.Common contains the DataAdapter base class. See if this works.

Comment: any idea where I can find the dll for system.data.common

Comment: In your Solution Explorer, look for the References node. Right click that and choose the option "Add Reference". Search there for the System.Data.Common dll.

Comment: I downloaded system.data.common and added to reference. also added dll to the application directory in window mobile. Still having same error

Comment: I have downloaded from http://www.search-dll.com/dll-files/download/system.data.common.dll.html

Comment: No. Add it from your references dialog in Visual Studio. What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I downloaded and then added from "Add reference" but In device I copied manually. Is that correct?

Comment: You should be able to add it directly from your add references dialog in visual studio. What Visual Studio version are you using?

Comment: See here: [.NET Compact Framework Data Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa275630(v=sql.80).aspx)